# Checking for User Role in Views Field with Twig

Tags: views, 8, theming

I'm currently building a view, where different Links should be displayed in a field, based on the currently logged in users role.

I've read a bit into Twig, but haven't found anything similar yet (if it is even possible).

Answer (score 3):

First, you should not do security by role.  It should be done by checking for a permission.

In general...Twig gets passed a user variable from Drupal that can be used for this.  There is a hasPermissions method.  Here's a sample code snippet.

```
  {% if user.hasPermission('administer eck entities') %}
      <a href='{{ add_url }}'>Add tab</a>
  {% endif %}
```

If you must use roles, there should be an hasRole() method on the user object that is passed in.  (See [User Object api docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Entity%21User.php/class/User/8.2.x))

For Views:

Views has limited twig like support in the GUI but does not support all the functions of the underlying twig functions.  To check for user permissions in a header, you will either need to use the hook_preprocess_views_view() or create your own view specific template, e.g. views-view--view-name.html.php in your theme. You will need to process the header (or footer) variables in these to get the permission specific info into the view.

If you want to limit specific fields, you can use the field specific hook and templates as well.

Comment: Not really a security issue so abit harsh to flag the OP on that. Though just showing/hiding a link as you suggest for security is. Your checks should be on the page you're linking to so using either hasPermission or role in this case isn't really a problem

Comment: `{% if user.hasPermission('InstrumentAddOther') %}
      <a href='/i/addo'>Add Other</a>
{% else %}
      <a href='/i/add'>Add Normal</a>
{% endif %}`
This is what I put in the field "Global: Custom Text" in my view. 
I certainly have the mentioned permission, but I still get the second link displayed. Anything I'm doing wrong there?

Comment: Didn't say it was a security (breach) issue.  Using permission rather than roles is a well know best practice for writing secure Drupal applications.  It is why there is a permission page. FWIW, my example does have url security to back it up.  However, if the twig template was to display non-link secure information, it is definitely better to link it to a right than a role since it can be done the standard admin way rather than having to change code... the people probably forgot about.  Or having to modify code to add new roles/rename roles.

Comment: Sorry, missed the view part.  Views don't currently have all the twig functionality.  Modifying answer.